# Netmiko run commands in list of devices

Tags: python, python-3.x

Team,

I have below requirement. Please help me to create a Python 3 script.

1. Our organization has 200 routers and switches which stored in cvs file (script should use this .csv file )
2. In those devices, some of the enabled ssh and some are telnet (script should check first ssh, if fails then try telnet)
3. We have two user names and passwords (like before script should use one user name and password if fail use next one)
4. Then check command out put of show "access-list"
5. If the output does not have access-list 100 configured then script need to configure that and capture to one file and save.

Comment: Sorry, but SO is not a free coding service. It is expected that you show at least some code you already have and present a specific problem when you get stuck.

Comment: You can start looking at the example at https://github.com/ktbyers/pynet-ons-jul17/blob/master/threads_procs/threads_show_ver.py